# Overlay in Scheme (Racket)

Tags: scheme, overlay, racket

I am trying to design a function named add-frame that takes an image and surrounds it with a one-pixel black border on all four sides. Here is what I have:

```
(define (horizontal-line x)
(line x 0 "black"))

(define (vertical-line x)
(line 0 x "black"))

(define (add-left-border height design color)
  (overlay/align "left" "top"
                 (vertical-line height)
                 (square height design color)))

(define (add-right-border height design color)
  (overlay/align "right" "top"
                 (vertical-line height)
                 (square height design color)))

(define (add-top-border height design color)
  (overlay/align "right" "top"
                 (horizontal-line height)
                 (square height design color)))

(define (add-bottom-border height design color)
  (overlay/align "right" "bottom"
                 (horizontal-line height)
                 (square height design color)))

(define (add-frame height design color)
  (overlay (square height design color)
           (add-left-border height design color)
           (add-right-border height design color)
           (add-top-border height design color)
           (add-bottom-border height design color)))
```

When I run "add-frame" I am returned with an image of a square with just the left border. How do I make the rest of the border appear on the returned square?

Comment: You can edit your post by clicking on the “edit” button below the tags.

Comment: Out of curiosity, is this a homework question?

Comment: How are `vertical-line` and `horizontal-line` defined?  (I couldn't get your program to run)

Comment: @LeifAndersen yes. We are working our way towards making a game of tetris.

Comment: @soegaard I just added the definitions

Answer (score 1):

This expression

```
(overlay/align "left" "top"
               (vertical-line height)
               (square height design color))
```

will correctly add a vertical line to the left of a square.

And this expression

```
(overlay/align "right" "top"
               (vertical-line height)
               (square height design color))
```

will correctly add a vertical line to the right of a square.

However - if you put the two images on top of each other - then 
since they are of the same size you will only see the top one.

To fix the problem (partially) you can add a transparent
line on the other side of the square.

A better solution is to pass the image on which the line is to 
be added.

That is change, say, `add-left-border` to:

```
(define (add-left-border height design color image)
  (overlay/align "left" "top"
                 (vertical-line height)
                 image))
```

which will add the left border on top of the image.

Something like this:

```
(define (horizontal-line x)
  (line x 1 "black"))

(define (vertical-line x)
  (line 1 x "black"))

(define (add-left-border height design color image)
  (overlay/align "left" "top"
                 (vertical-line height)
                 image))

(define (add-right-border height design color image)
  (overlay/align "right" "top"
                 (vertical-line height)
                 image))

(add-left-border 80 "solid" "red"
                 (add-right-border 80 "solid" "red"
                                   (circle 40 "solid" "red")))
```

Note: It is better to use `image-width` and `image-height` on the image in order to get the correct size automatically.

Comment: I can get the individual left and right lines to show up on the square. I cannot get them to show up at the same time.

Comment: @Brett Hi Brett I have added a partial solution.